# How do I adjust a Double Demountable Hinge?

Tags: doors

I have 2 pairs of cabinet doors that catch against each other when I open or shut either cabinet door. How do I adjust the hinges so they close “nicely”?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are adjustment screws on these hinges which move the pivot in and out. On our cabinets these are Pozidriv screws, an evolution of Phillips but not fully compatible. A Phillips driver does not acceptably engage Pozidrive screw heads.

Pozidriv drivers are labelled PZ1, PZ2, etc., and Phillips drivers are labelled PH1, PH2, . . .

Pozidriv screws generally have little tic marks on the face of the head radiating from the center. https://shop4fasteners.co.uk/blog/pozidriv-vs-phillips/

Comment: Imagine how life would be so much better if there were only robertsons.

Comment: I learned something new today.  ;-)

Comment: @JACK there is reportedly yet another "Phillips like" screw head and driver called JIS (Japanese Industry Standard) https://chapmanmfg.com/blogs/news/phillips-bits-vs-jis-bits-whats-the-difference#:~:text=Chances%20are%20that's%20because%20it's,the%20point%20of%20the%20driver.